# How to connect to the north anchors of triangular (leaf) nodes in tikz-qtree?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes, tikz-qtree, edge

How to make the edges from `x` (resp. `y`) to connect to the north anchors of the triangular leaf nodes `A` and `B` (resp. `C`)?

Note that this should not change the edge style between `x` and `y`. Therefore, the [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/379964/23098) with `edge from parent path = {(\tikzparentnode) -- (\tikzchildnode.north)}` is unsatisfactory.

[image: qtree-triangle-node]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance = 35pt, sibling distance = 20pt,
  edge from parent/.style = {
    draw, edge from parent path = {(\tikzparentnode) -- (\tikzchildnode)}}]
  \tikzset{every internal node/.style = {draw, circle, red, font = \Large}}
  \tikzset{every leaf node/.style = {draw, blue, regular polygon, regular polygon sides = 3, inner sep = 1pt}}

  \Tree [.$y$ 
      \edge [red, very thick]; 
      [.$x$
        $A$
        $B$
      ] 
      $C$
    ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an explicit `edge from parent path` to your edge between x and y and use the `.north` path for the rest:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance = 35pt, sibling distance = 20pt,
  edge from parent/.style = {
    draw, edge from parent path = {(\tikzparentnode) -- (\tikzchildnode.north)}}]
  \tikzset{every internal node/.style = {draw, circle, red, font = \Large}}
  \tikzset{every leaf node/.style = {draw, blue, regular polygon, regular polygon sides = 3, inner sep = 1pt}}

  \Tree [.$y$ 
      \edge [red, very thick,edge from parent path = {(\tikzparentnode) -- (\tikzchildnode)}]; 
      [.$x$
        $A$
        $B$
      ] 
      $C$
    ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]